# How to install.packages of R 4.2.0?

Tags: r, macos

I try to fix the following error in the code.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
install_github("sangwon-hyun/omd", subdir = "omd")
```

Comment: Did the package installation finish without error? If so try restarting the R session, then `library(devtools)`.

Comment: @neilfws I have restarted the R session but there is still the same error.

Comment: Try restarting R, ensure a clean/empty environment and then try re-installing `devtools`.

Comment: Try `remove.packages('devtools'); install.packages('devtools')`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks. But there is still a error when I use the `library(omd, quietly = TRUE)`.

Comment: Ok, seems it can't find dependencies try `install_github("sangwon-hyun/omd", subdir = "omd", dependencies=TRUE)`, not sure what `subdir` does though.

Comment: @jay.sf I add 'dependencies=TRUE'. But it still shows the same error?

Comment: What happens when you manually `install.packages('raster')`?

Comment: @jay.sf I added the result in my question. But it still report 'Show in New Window
 Error in library(omd, quietly = TRUE) : there is no package called ‘omd’'

Comment: You have no [`gdal`](https://gdal.org/) installed, appears to be fun on macos, open a terminal and try this: https://mits003.github.io/studio_null/2021/07/install-gdal-on-macos/ or work through this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/155403

Comment: @jay.sf I used R not python? Do I need to install goal?

Comment: @jay.sf It still shows error.